# Use previous row value in pandas apply()

Tags: pandas, group-by, apply

I have a rather complex problem at hand.  I have a dataframe as below:

```
data = {'id':  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'counter': [1,2,3, 1,2,3],
        'p': ['1', '2', '8', '1', '4', '8'],
   }



df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    id  cntr    p
0   a   1       1
1   a   2       2
2   a   3       8
3   b   1       1
4   b   2       4
5   b   3       8
```

I need to create/add two columns (`col1`, `col2`) to the dataframe and assign values to them based on the values of the existing columns. I also need to group by `id` which has two groups namely `a` and `b`.

Now for each group the value of `col1` when `cntr =1`  should be same as `id`.  And when `cntr!=1` the value should be the value from previous row in column `col2` .  The rest of the values are derived from function `user_func`.

In case of `col2`,  for each group the value of `col2` when `pu=8` should be same as `id` but otherwise it requires to pass the value from previous row in column `col1` to the `user_func`. And based on that the value of `col2` is derived.

for col1:

> when cntr =1 then col1 = id
>
> else  col1 = col2[-1].value

for col2:

> when pu = 8 then  col2 = id
>
> else col2 = user_func(col1)

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
    id     cntr pu  col1  col2
0   a       1   1   a     x
1   a       2   2   x     y
2   a       3   8   y     a
3   b       1   1   b     p
4   b       2   4   p     q
5   b       3   8   q     b



    data = {'id':  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'counter': [1,2,3, 1,2,3],
    'p': ['1', '2', '8', '1', '4', '8'],

    'o': ['a', 'x', 'y', 'b', 'p', 'q'],
    'd': ['x', 'y','a', 'p','q','b']
    
    }

result = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my attempt:

```
def user_func(col1):
    if col1 == 'x':
        return 'y'
    elif col1=='a':
        return 'x'
    elif col1=='b':
        return 'p'
    elif col1=='p':
        return 'q'

df['col2'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['id'] if x['p']==8 else user_func(x['col1']), axis =1)

df['col1'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['id'] if x['cntr']==1 else x['col2'].shift(-1), axis =1)
```

There are couple of problems with the above code.

first, i use `apply` function with `groupby` which does not work.

Second, how to pass the value of previous row in lambda function.

Comment: Where are `x` and `p` coming from?

Comment: Using `apply()` with `axis=1` will deliver a row to the called function.  So `shift(-1)` won't work in that environment since the function only has access to a single row.  Also, in general, `shift(1)` not `shift(-1)` will give you the previous value in a column.

Comment: Also it seems like there is a chicken and egg problem in your logic.  To fully set col1 value you need access to a col2 value.  And to fully set the col2 value you need access to a col1 value.

Comment: @mozway, x and p also comes from user_func which i have now edited. Thanks!

Comment: @jch,  will ´pipe´ function work instead of apply ? its not really a chicken and egg problem. I have edited user_func as pointed by mozway.

Comment: you don't need to use groupby because aggregation in groups isn't needed. the problem that is hard to solve is that col2 values is based on col1 and col1 is based on col2 and both of them start empty.

Comment: the only solution I could see in this case is to iterate over the rows which is very inefficient if you have large data.

Comment: @Qdr ,   Iteration is what I want to avoid.  The values of columns are based on but not entirely dependent on each other. The chain begins with   col1 value taking column "id" value and ends with col2 value again  taking column "id" value.

Comment: I have a feeling that this could all be done in a vectorized manner.  The `user_func()` could instead be done via nested `np.where()`'s.  Unfortunately I'm running out of time for now.  Would need to fully digest the sequence needed to set col1 and col2.  Might be able to look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned in the comments, first, you don't need to use groupby because there is no aggregation on a group level. you could just use `df.loc[,]` and `np.where()`.

in your example, `user_func` is incomplete so I assumed the desired values from the output dataframe you've provided.

I was able to solve it with a while loop.

```
df.loc[df['counter'] == 1, 'col1'] = df['id']
df.loc[df['p'] == 8, 'col2'] = df['id']
while np.any(df['col2'].isna()) or np.any(df['col1'].isna()):
    df.loc[df['counter'] != 1, 'col1'] = df['col2'].shift(1)
    df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'x', 'y',
                          np.where(df['col1'] == 'a', 'x',
                                   np.where(df['col1'] == 'b', 'p',
                                            np.where(df['col1'] == 'y', 'a',
                                                     np.where(df['col1'] == 'p', 'q',
                                                              np.where(df['col1'] == 'q', 'b', None))))))
```

this is faster than iterating over the rows as the while loop will iterate 5 time in the worst case.

Comment: I think there could be a cleaner way to express the conditions beside np.where, in terms of efficiency, I'm not sure whether there is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would perhaps still need group by because in the real data there not only two groups but many more. And the user func is complex. Here for simplicity I have hard coded the values in function but that's not the real case. I need to put the question more succinctly.